# Telerik RadEditor - Is there a way to export the data as a ByteArray instead of just exporting as a PDF straight to the browser?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, telerik, arrays, radeditor

I am using one of Telerik's ASP.NET controls the RadEditor, and I need to be able to get the data content out as a ByteArray so that I can then attach it to an email.  I was wondering if that is possible to do?
There is a built in function that allows you to export the content in a PDF file format to the browser by calling myEditor.ExportToPDF().  The problem is that this is a void method that just outputs to the browser so I can not use that.  There is also an OnExportContent event on the server-side but I am not sure if I can get the content as a ByteArray from this event? There is also the problem that it would still output to the browser as that event is called after you call the export function.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-export-to-pdf.html - the documentation will show you how. About halfway in the middle you will see how to take the output and redirect the page back to itself to avoid the pdf streaming to the browser.